# Unable to install 'Trix' in an existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, trix

I've spent some time on trying to add function of uploading, posting and displaying images in my application. I've tried different methods, eventually finding out that 'Trix' is what I need to reach that goal.
The issue here is that my application structure is quite different from those that I see in 'trix' tutorials, and I have no idea what I am doing :(((

Let's start from the fact that my application.js is located in ->

```
[app]>
     -[javascript]
       -[packs]
        -application.js
```

and looks very different from what I see in tutorials. However, I tried to adapt like so -

```
...

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('trix')
...
```

Instead of writing `//= require trix`.
Another slight difference is that my "application.css" is not ".scss", but I figured it is not that big of a deal. So I went ahead and pasted `*= require trix` in there.
At first , when I loaded page I've got an error   `couldn't find file 'trix' with type 'text/css'` , but after restarting server it wasn't there anymore (which is normal). Next step would be adding the code ... but it seems that most people have `_form.html.erb`. And here is where I need help. my "Post" structure is like this ->

```
[views]>
 - edit.html.erb
 - index.html.erb
 - new.html.erb
 - show.html.erb
```

where `new.html.erb` contains the form for submitting a post ->

```
<div class="main posts-new">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="form-heading">Create a new post</h1>
    <%= form_tag("/posts/create") do %>
      <div class="form">
        <div class="form-body">
          <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <div class="form-error">
              <%= message %>
            </div>
          <% end %>

          <textarea name="content"><%= @post.content %></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="Post">
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is where the difference really confuses me... Where do I add 'trix' ? I've tried replacing  **textarea**  with **trix-editor**, the only changes I've got , where two small overlapping squares instead of submit form.
Help. :(

Comment: Please include the *exact* error you're getting.

Comment: Does Trix require CSS as well as JavaScript to be bundled in? It's worth checking that both the CSS and JavaScript have loaded properly.

Comment: Thank you for response! I've edited post with an error,since it no longer occurs, can't really add too much to that. I've also tried to see if I've overlooked something , like ```.js ``` and  ```.css``` for 'trix'. I came across yet another tutorial where they provided those files - for updating 'trix'. I've decided to include those files as well and did everything according to this tutorial - https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/trix-rails/2.0.0 . Yet again, nothing but a tiny square to signify changes...

Comment: ..oh and CSS/JS files are not loading.